# How should I write this query to filter column with nvarchar datatype and has '00' value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

table-A with SECTION nvarchar column with following data examples:

```
SECTION
00
01
100
101
110
1000
1001
1234
2000
2001
2002
```

Tried using cast:

```
SELECT
CAST(SECTION as int) as b,
FROM a
WHERE
SECTION Between 1001 and 2001
```

I get "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'OO' to data type int."

Tried with '' on where statement:

```
SELECT
CAST(SECTION as int) as b,
FROM a
WHERE
SECTION Between '1001' and '2001'
```

I get result that includes 110

How should I write this so I just get the following result:

```
1001
1234
2000
2001
```

Comment: `WHERE CAST(SECTION as int) Between 1000 and 2000`  I don't see 'OO' in the data.  Sorting as a Varchar would return those results - I don't know why you would expect differently.

Comment: but the problem is with the value  `OO`, as in two letters O

Comment: I still get this "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'OO' to data type int."

Comment: Then you lied here: 'table-A with SECTION nvarchar column with following data:' because OO is not in there.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: If you expect to order the values as integers, then the data type for that column should be an integer - not a nvarchar.  Because there are no leading zeros, you will always get '1000', '110', '12000'.  Try it in Excel as text

Comment: Unfortunately that's how its setup as nvarchar. Its for a table to show how many sections a class was offered. Example: multiple Math class offered at the same semester would be listed in the table as Math 00, Math 01, Math 1001, Math 2222, etc

Answer (score 0):

The following is standard SQL and likely to work in most databases for your data examples:

```
SELECT CAST(SECTION as int) as b
FROM a
WHERE SECTION LIKE '1____';
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like value 00(zero zero) is actually O(letter "O"). Because if you have entered all integers in SECTION column, below query mentioned in your example will return correct result .

```
SELECT
CAST(SECTION as int) as b,
FROM a
WHERE
SECTION Between 1001 and 2001
```

For your second query, If you will order by records by Section column result will be as below

```
select * from a order by SECTION    
    Result :- 
    SECTION
    00
    01
    100
    1000
    1001
    101
    110
    1234
    2000
    2001
    2002
```

For your second query, values from 1001 to 2001 will be returned, because SECTION is a nvarchar column so it will fetch data in a alphabetical order.

Comment: I've searched with 'O%' (not zero) nothing comes up in that table